# Allocate CPU and memory resources to specific users or groups in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, analytics

I have Postgres DB and I am looking if it is possible to create users for our analytics team and allocate CPU and memory resources to that users in Postgres. Something similar to WLM on Redshift -> distribute resources per users.
If it is not posible any advice is welcome?

Would like to solve this without rising new db replica instance because current cost for one instance is 1700 EUR, and would like to avoid another one 1700 EUR montly bill.

Answer (score 0):

Not in any good way.  You can set the default work_mem and statement_timeout on a per user basis (`ALTER USER ... SET ...`).  But this is merely cooperative, as the user can countermand those settings if they wish to.

And the settings might also have perverse effects. A lower work_mem could cause the query to adopt a more CPU intensive plan, for example.  And if a query times out after 100 seconds, maybe they will give up or maybe they will run it 500 more times in an attempt to get it to eventually complete--wasting even more CPU while never getting the job done.

This is largely a business problem, not a programming one.  If you assign your workers the job to do X, but won't allow them to use the resources they need to do it, then what do you hope to happen?